# Projecting an entity to an anonymous object while some of its navigation properties might be null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, binding

I hope the question isn't confusing, what I'm trying to do is binding a list of anonymous object to a grid, I have a `class` `Client`, I am project a client into a list of anonymous object so that I can show its details in the grid, like this:

```
this.gridControl1.DataSource = _clients.Select(c => new
{
    c.ClientId,
    c.FirstName,
    c.LastName,
    c.Details.Country, //throws NullReferenceException since I added a 
                       //client with no details.
    c.Details.City,
    c.Details.Adress,
    c.Details.Email
}).OrderByDescending(c => c.ClientId);
```

Problem is some clients might not have details added yet..when trying to bind I get a `NullReferenceException` obviously..
The reason I'm doing a projection is to avoid having a column `Details` in the grid which is useless.

So, any solution? or a different approach to encounter this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that fields are strings, try

```
country = c.Details != null ? c.Details.Country : "", // or null or another
                                                      // appropriate default value
```

etc. instead of

```
c.Details.Country
```

Comment: I've already tried this it's not possible inside the projection, I get:  `Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.`

Comment: Did you try `somename = c.Details != null ? c.Details.Country : ""`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator to do this:

```
c.Details == null ? null : c.Details.Country
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing how Client is created I can't be sure what would work for you.  Here are some suggestions:

1. Instantiate Client with a "blank" Details object which has string.Empty in all properties.
2. Make Client.Details a private property, then expose public properties (Country, City, etc) which have only getters and which return empty strings when the private Details object is null.  If you need to access the Details object externally use a method instead of a property:

   ```
   class Details
   {
       public string Country { get; set; }
   }
   class Client
   {
       private Details _details;
       public string Country
       {
           get
           {
               return _details == null ? string.Empty : _details.Country;
           }
       }
       public Details GetDetails()
       {
           return _details;
       }
   }
   ```

This would have the added benefit of allowing you to eliminate the anonymous selection, since the Details object would no longer be a Property and therefore ignored by the binding process.  You could bind your clients collection directly to the grid.

Comment: I like this approach, but I'm using POCO classes with navigation properties , and Details is `virtual` this will change the structure of the class.